# Pass C++ Object so Lua can use it

Tags: c++, lua, luabind

I understand with Luabind that I can expose classes and then instances of those classes can be created in lua.

```
module[L_state]
   [
      class_<Player>("Player")
      .def(constructor<>())
      .def("Update",&Player::Update)
   ];

test.lua
player = Player()
player:Update()
```

But what if I wanted to create that player instance in C++ because I want to call it's members in C++, but I also want to expose that same instance of player to Lua so it can still call it's functions like:

```
player:Update()
```

Comment: You can call the lua functions from C++ to create and access the instance if you want to keep things done this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push the value onto the Lua stack via luabind:

```
Player p;
luabind::globals(L)["player"] = p;
```

a runnable example: [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/d-led/lua_cpp_tryout/builds/58761283), [source](https://github.com/d-led/lua_cpp_tryout/blob/29659750/try_luabridge.cpp).

P.S. beware of object lifetime and ownership issues. The [LuaBridge](http://vinniefalco.github.com/LuaBridge) manual can be of help to plan a strategy of shared object lifetime management. + an updated [LuaBind manual](http://public.vrac.iastate.edu/vancegroup/docs/luabind/) for the LuaBind lifetime policies.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thanks! For my process the object will live for the entire application so not an issue.